# How do I recover from a torn wrist ligament?

Tags: hand, irreversible-damage, wrist, tear-torn, ligament

I tore my wrist ligaments and cracked a bone when punching. It is the 4th week and my hand is better but when I try to do push ups it hurts. My doc told me that ligament tear never heals. Is it true?

Comment: Which bone? Scaphoid fractures are serious business and should be surgically repaired. I know this first hand (no pun intended). I broke my scaphoid as a teenager and am now looking at wrist fusion to relieve the sometimes intense pain I experience now. Look up osteonecrosis of the wrist.

Answer (score -2):

I have a similar problem. So I was snowboarding when I wiped out and slammed, twisted, and poped my knee on the hard snow. It hurted! Anyway I want to the doctor after a couple weeks to determine if any bones were broken, there wasn't and I was told that the X-ray didn't show any sign of tear. But then I was hand examined and I had a swollen part of my knee that indicated that I tore my meniscus. Doctor said if you don't feel better in two weeks come back(to have surgery ). (Ok this anwser is taking too long).

Anyway the accident happened in January and my knee still hurts.(after I started exercising it started to feel better. I have read that exercising(not to harsh obviously) that will actually help. This will cause the muscle to grow around my knee and strengthen it.  That will do the same with your wrist. Every part of the human body is able to repair itself.  Babies can regrow  finger tips(part of their finger) for crying out loud.  Now the speed of your recovery depends on the listed items below.

1. Age
2. Current state of health (smoking....etc will slow cellur process which is essential to any type of body repair.

   3. Exercising if not done right.

Ok... Finally now I am going to tell you what to do about your wrist.

**How to help your body recover**

I can't guarantee that you will recover from your injury but I do have some tips that hopefully will help. If you don't recover you might have to get surgery cause I am guessing you don't want to hurt forever.

You should apply ice for 25 minutes a day on the wrist. This will help reduce pain.

Next you should slowly exercise your wrist. Look the exercises up.
Don't over do it.

Get alot of sleep and eat correctly. Healing will be quicker.

A torn ligament takes 6-9 months to heal.
Make sure, when you sitting at a desk, to not lay your wrist on the border of the desk this will put a sharp pressure on your wrist causing it to hurt. Don't put any unnecessary pressure on your wrist!

Sorry if this anwser is long, once I start typing I don't stop!

Listen to your doctor not stack exchange. Although it got me thinking when he/she said 
torn ligaments *never* heal. This is not true under normal conditions.

Comment: No, sorry, babies cannot grow new fingers. I'll stop there because your post is full of stuff like that. The one solid answer you provided was this: `Listen to your doctor not stack exchange.`

Comment: Under normal conditions if a babies finger is cut off, that finger can be regrown.

Comment: Not the whole finger either

Comment: Part of it, like the tip